# Access EditText.getText().toString() inside some other class

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a custom dialog inside

```
public class NewPartnerDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener
```

And I call it from other class (activity)

```
private void showCustomDialog() {
    NewPartnerDialog customDialog = new NewPartnerDialog(this);
    customDialog.show();
}
```

And it works (it does show), but I have a little problem. In it I have 3 EditText fields. How can I retreieve those typed values and pass them into some other class construtor. Here is the code.

```
public class NewPartnerDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
public NewPartnerDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mainContext = context;

    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_new_partner);
    setTitle("Dialog");

    finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finish);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finish);
    finish.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {       
    if (v == finish) {
        Partner.addNewPartner(mainContext, name.getText().toString(), address.getText().toString(), city.getText().toString());
    } else if (v == cancel) {
        dismiss();
    }
}

private static EditText name;
private static EditText address;
private static EditText city;
private static Context mainContext;
private Button finish;
private Button cancel;
```

}

The error is obivusly here

```
if (v == finish) {
        Partner.addNewPartner(mainContext, name.getText().toString(), address.getText().toString(), city.getText().toString());
    }
```

because it says NullPointerException but how to fix it?

Comment: just some helper class. all it does matter is that it's arguments are (Context, String, String, String). If i replace this last chunk of code with "Partner.addNewPartner(mainContext, "ABC", "ABCD", "ABCDE");" everything works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making name, address, and city final:

```
private static final EditText name, address, city;
```

Not certain that will do the trick, but you may try.

EDIT: You may need to make `finish` and `cancel` final as well.

Comment: But if I make them final I can't assign Views to them - "name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);" because they are already final (constants). The problem is that onClick method takes empty parameters (name,address,city), not the one defined in constructor.

Comment: You should still be able to assign them in the constructor; they're not locked from changing until you've assigned to them once. You may not need the `static` modifier either. Try just `private final EditText`. I'd test if I could but I don't have Eclipse at work.

Comment: Yes, without static I can assign them once, but still doesn't work. I don't get it, I have a constuctor and empty variables name,address,city. I call the constructor and initialize those variables to their Views. But onClick just isn't picking them up? EDIT: In log it's just (any of these 3 variables)...null.

Comment: :( I have to say I'm not sure, then.

Comment: Huh, I should shoot myself - now :D I changed before some variables in .XML so it's not .name - it's .partnerName so..ofcourse it's null because it doesn't exist :D Anyway, this code up-there - is just fine ;)

Comment: lmao. I wish I could say I've not done that before, but... :P Glad you figured it out!